# Where to find the default DNS resolver configuration of a Reactive Spring Boot / WebFlux application? Is TCP fallback enabled?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

We have multiple Reactive Spring Boot applications (WebFlux) running in Azure Container Apps. Since they run in Azure we can see some sporadic netty DNS resolver timeouts which we try to track down. We haven't seen them on premises. One hint is that this could be a UDP trunction problem and we should enable TCP fallback for the netty DNS resolver.

Now I would like to know two things:

1. Where to find the netty dns resolver default configuration? Is this in Spring, Reactor or the Reactor HTTP/TCP client? I want to check if TCP fallback is already enabled or not.
2. How to change this default to make it work for the whole JVM/application?

I tried to find it in the Github code repos but got lost.

Sources:

- [netty DnsNameResolverTimeoutException](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/13660)
- [Redisson using TCP fallback which is available but not enabled by default in the netty DNS resolver](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/5137)

Comment: AFAIK DNS uses UDP anyway? But that said, this is too broad for stackoverflow, there is nothing here to go off for debugging. Please check [ask].

Comment: In general UDP is a good starting point. It gets more complicated if a DNS response exceeds 512 bytes. Depending on the client either EDNS with larger DNS responses or TCP is used. Larger DNS responses are very common for CDNs with many ressource records, IPv6 or DNSSEC in the response. In Azure we often have them because the provided DNS server sometimes includes a large number of servers in the authoritative section.
But that is a topic for the linked netty github issue. This question is about where to find the netty dns resolver configuration used in a Spring WebFlux application.

Comment: TCP fallback is enabled by default - see https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/b921d2e6696f0e0c2937cf213eb9531db61a15fc/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/transport/NameResolverProvider.java#L552-L553

Comment: @violeta-georgieva Thank you very much. That is what I was looking for. If you make this an answer instead of a comment I can mark this as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactor Netty enables by default the TCP fallback.
You can see the configuration [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/b921d2e6696f0e0c2937cf213eb9531db61a15fc/reactor-netty-core/src/main/java/reactor/netty/transport/NameResolverProvider.java#L552-L553)